# Can someone explain me this Oracle SQL Command?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ALTER TABLE "APPLICATIONS_SRV_STORAGE"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "APPL_SRV_STORAGE_APPLICAT_FK1"
    FOREIGN KEY ("APP_ID")
    REFERENCES "APPLICATIONS" ("APP_ID")
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ENABLE;
```

Does it mean: When something on table APPLICATIONS is deleted, delte altough the entry in APPLICATION_SRV_STORAGE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The addition of DELETE CASCADE means that when a row in APPLICATIONS is deleted, any rows in APPLICATIONS_SRV_STORAGE that reference its APP_ID will also be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `APPLICATIONS` will be considered the parent and `APPLICATIONS_SRV_STORAGE` will be the child, the connection being made through `APP_ID`. When the parent is deleted, then all the children will also be deleted (*cascading*).

Reference: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php (Couldn't find the official one.)

Answer (score 3):

This adds a new constraint with the name `APPL_SRV_STORAGE_APPLICAT_FK1` to the table `APPLICATIONS_SRV_STORAGE`.

The constraint itself is that for every value in the column `APPLICATIONS_SRV_STORAGE.APP_ID`, there must be a matching value in `APPLICATIONS.APP_ID`. `APPLICATIONS.APP_ID` can contain values not contained in `APPLICATIONS_SRV_STORAGE.APP_ID`.

In addition to that, if an `APP_ID` is deleted from the table `APPLICATIONS`, then all rows from `APPLICATIONS_SRV_STORAGE` with the same ID are deleted as well.

At creation time, the constraint is enabled (Oracle allows you to disable constraints temporarily).